# Wordpress custom fields not showing the html inside a loop

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, nested-loops, advanced-custom-fields

I'm kinda new to PHP, so don't hate me.
I am using Advanced Custom Fields and I have problem.

I need to access the fields for registrating people and one of the data they can input is their social networks. However, those can be 0, 1, 2, 3, every social network they want.

I want an "if statement" to check if the field is filled with some information, then display it or else don't display it, but it does only show the "the_field" text, it gets rid of all HTML tags around it.

Here is the latest code I've used, inside a PHP (have_posts()) loop.

```
<ul class="social">
<li><a target="_blank" class="facebook" href="<?php the_field('facebook'); ?>">X</a></li>
<li><a target="_blank" class="linkedin" href="<?php the_field('linkedin'); ?>">v</a></li>
<?php 
    $strtwitter = the_field('twitter');
    $strtwitter = strlen($strtwitter);
    if ($strtwitter > 10) :
?>
    <li><a target="_blank" class="twitter" href="<?php the_field('twitter'); ?>">_</a></li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This is what shows up. Should appear the Twitter Bird:

http://prntscr.com/8k76p3

This is the developer's browser console source, with no HTML or PHP on the Twitter tag:

http://prntscr.com/8k76ry

What am I doing wrong?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `get_field( "text_field" )` with conditional statements

```
if( get_field( "text_field" ) ): ?>
    <p><?php the_field( "text_field" ); ?></p>
<?php endif;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO @BrunoConfortin. Please mark this answer as the correct one and refrain from adding "resolved" in the title.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the "correct answer" icon. Thank you :D

Answer (score -1):

if you want the custom field data into variable then you have to use like `get_the_field('custom_field_name');` not like `the_field('custom_field_name');` Replace your code with below code.

```
<ul class="social">
    <li><a target="_blank" class="facebook" href="<?php the_field('facebook'); ?>">X</a></li>
    <li><a target="_blank" class="linkedin" href="<?php the_field('linkedin'); ?>">v</a></li>
    <?php 
    $strtwitter = get_field('twitter');
    $strtwitter = strlen($strtwitter);
    if ($strtwitter > 10) :
        ?>
        <li><a target="_blank" class="twitter" href="<?php the_field('twitter'); ?>">_</a></li>
    <?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Following the comment below, this is wrong:

$strtwitter = get_the_field('twitter');

get_THE_field -> should be only get_field.

And then it works flawlessly. Thank you. <hug>